# Loading google maps API from php file

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, html, php

I've been trying to load some GeoJSON data into a map, using Google Maps API.
When I save my file as .html the map shows up just fine, and it shows the data I want to see (a Linestring). I'm using Xampp to load Apache and view files on my browser.

However, I want my code to run the query that produces the GeoJSON data, and I know how to do that in php. But as soon as I change the extension to php, it breaks.
Here's the code:

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Google Map</h1>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC2HeV9gPl_FFELM6_6hsSGd0HDqMD4GK4&callback=initMap"></script>
<div id="map" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
function initMap() {
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
 center: {lng: -58.47, lat: -32.68},
 zoom: 15
 });
//var json_data = "<?php echo $arr ?>";
//map.data.addGeoJson(json_data);
map.data.addGeoJson({ "type": "FeatureCollection",
 "features": [
   { "type": "Feature",
     "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [102.0, 0.5]},
     "properties": {"prop0": "value0"}
     },
   { "type": "Feature",
     "geometry": {
                   
   "type": "LineString",
   "coordinates": [[-58.472229004,-32.686359406],[-58.47233963,-32.686649323],[-58.472431183,-32.68680954],[-58.472568512,-32.68693924],[-58.4725914,-32.687000275],[-58.472618103,-32.68724823],[-58.472751617,-32.6875],[-58.472869873,-32.687660217],[-58.472938538,-32.687950134],[-58.473041534,-32.688251495],[-58.473121643,-32.688541412],[-58.473220825,-32.688838959],[-58.473331451,-32.68901825],[-58.473468781,-32.689128876],[-58.473548889,-32.689189911],[-58.473571777,-32.689201355],[-58.473770142,-32.689430237],[-58.473861694,-32.689609528],[-58.473899841,-32.689811707],[-58.473949432,-32.689849854],[-58.474048615,-32.689910889],[-58.474048615,-32.68996048],[-58.474010468,-32.690021515],[-58.473930359,-32.690151215],[-58.474010468,-32.690441132],[-58.474128723,-32.690719604],[-58.474250793,-32.690990448],[-58.474479675,-32.6912117],[-58.474651337,-32.6913414],[-58.474681854,-32.69134903],[-58.474830627,-32.691368103],[-58.475021362,-32.691429138],[-58.475040436,-32.691440582],[-58.475128174,-32.691520691],[-58.475200653,-32.691631317],[-58.475330353,-32.691898346],[-58.475479126,-32.692001343],[-58.475799561,-32.692100525],[-58.475959778,-32.692211151],[-58.47618866,-32.692440033],[-58.476398468,-32.692661285],[-58.476589203,-32.692909241],[-58.476791382,-32.693180084],[-58.477020264,-32.693408966],[-58.477241516,-32.693611145],[-58.477550507,-32.693748474],[-58.477828979,-32.693920135],[-58.477928162,-32.693939209],[-58.478038788,-32.693920135],[-58.478061676,-32.693908691],[-58.478351593,-32.693759918],[-58.478610992,-32.693561554],[-58.478618622,-32.693538666],[-58.478691101,-32.693408966],[-58.478759766,-32.693130493],[-58.478900909,-32.692848206],[-58.479000092,-32.692558289],[-58.478981018,-32.692298889],[-58.478889465,-32.69203949],[-58.478721619,-32.691768646],[-58.478561401,-32.691509247],[-58.478309631,-32.691299438],[-58.478168488,-32.69121933],[-58.478149414,-32.69121933],[-58.477828979,-32.691150665],[-58.477790833,-32.691108704],[-58.477748871,-32.691040039],[-58.477748871,-32.69095993],[-58.477790833,-32.690898895],[-58.477901459,-32.690769196],[-58.477890015,-32.690670013],[-58.477878571,-32.69065094],[-58.477779388,-32.69039917],[-58.477790833,-32.690170288],[-58.477779388,-32.690151215],[-58.477668762,-32.689880371],[-58.477581024,-32.689678192],[-58.477329254,-32.68944931],[-58.477241516,-32.689430237],[-58.477210999,-32.689430237],[-58.47687912,-32.689468384],[-58.476860046,-32.68944931],[-58.476799011,-32.689380646],[-58.476821899,-32.689319611],[-58.476890564,-32.689281464],[-58.47718811,-32.689250946],[-58.477279663,-32.689239502],[-58.477298737,-32.689159393],[-58.477291107,-32.68914032],[-58.477218628,-32.688961029],[-58.477149963,-32.688659668],[-58.476951599,-32.688411713],[-58.476768494,-32.688148499],[-58.476741791,-32.688129425],[-58.476539612,-32.688030243],[-58.476501465,-32.687980652],[-58.476379395,-32.687709808],[-58.478729248,-32.690418243],[-58.478740692,-32.690479279],[-58.478870392,-32.690761566],[-58.478969574,-32.691020966],[-58.479049683,-32.691261292],[-58.479068756,-32.691268921],[-58.479118347,-32.691291809],[-58.479141235,-32.691291809],[-58.476238251,-32.687438965],[-58.476200104,-32.687240601],[-58.476200104,-32.687221527],[-58.476211548,-32.686988831],[-58.476200104,-32.686969757],[-58.476108551,-32.686698914],[-58.476081848,-32.686561584],[-58.476070404,-32.686279297],[-58.476020813,-32.685970306],[-58.476028442,-32.685951233],[-58.476070404,-32.685909271],[-58.476158142,-32.685871124],[-58.47618866,-32.685871124],[-58.476268768,-32.685878754],[-58.476291656,-32.685890198],[-58.47631073,-32.685901642],[-58.476379395,-32.685958862],[-58.476421356,-32.686031342],[-58.476528168,-32.686328888],[-58.476650238,-32.686569214],[-58.476760864,-32.686870575],[-58.47687149,-32.687000275],[-58.476890564,-32.687011719],[-58.476989746,-32.687099457],[-58.47700882,-32.687141418],[-58.47700882,-32.687221527],[-58.47700119,-32.687358856],[-58.477031708,-32.687438965],[-58.477199554,-32.687709808],[-58.477329254,-32.687980652],[-58.477531433,-32.688228607],[-58.477779388,-32.688388824],[-58.477901459,-32.688499451],[-58.477928162,-32.688568115],[-58.477920532,-32.688640594],[-58.477901459,-32.688690186],[-58.477828979,-32.688808441],[-58.477851868,-32.68888855],[-58.477909088,-32.688961029],[-58.477920532,-32.688968658],[-58.478149414,-32.689151764],[-58.478168488,-32.689258575],[-58.478210449,-32.689418793],[-58.478279114,-32.689498901],[-58.478420258,-32.689670563],[-58.478431702,-32.689731598],[-58.478439331,-32.689910889],[-58.478500366,-32.689998627],[-58.47851944,-32.690021515],[-58.478599548,-32.690059662],[-58.478839874,-32.690151215],[-58.478858948,-32.690189362],[-58.478858948,-32.690219879],[-58.478839874,-32.690250397],[-58.478759766,-32.690338135],[-58.479179382,-32.691268921],[-58.4792099,-32.6912117],[-58.479190826,-32.691131592],[-58.479179382,-32.691108704],[-58.479148865,-32.691001892],[-58.479160309,-32.690910339],[-58.479179382,-32.690879822],[-58.479309082,-32.690681458],[-58.479328156,-32.69052124],[-58.479290009,-32.690219879],[-58.479270935,-32.689918518],[-58.479301453,-32.689628601],[-58.4793396,-32.689319611],[-58.479328156,-32.689048767],[-58.479309082,-32.688751221],[-58.479290009,-32.68844986],[-58.4793396,-32.688278198],[-58.479488373,-32.688041687],[-58.479488373,-32.687980652],[-58.47946167,-32.68793869],[-58.479431152,-32.687908173],[-58.479221344,-32.687728882],[-58.479179382,-32.6876297],[-58.479179382,-32.687610626],[-58.4792099,-32.687511444],[-58.479228973,-32.687198639],[-58.479259491,-32.687019348],[-58.479320526,-32.68693161],[-58.479400635,-32.686878204],[-58.479499817,-32.686859131],[-58.479598999,-32.686851501],[-58.479660034,-32.686779022],[-58.479698181,-32.686618805],[-58.479740143,-32.686321259]]
   }
                   }]});
map.data.setStyle({
     strokeColor: "#FF0000",
     strokeOpacity: 0.8,
     strokeWeight: 10,
     });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

And this is what I want to add

```
<?php
    $connection = pg_connect ("host=localhost dbname=postgres user=postgres password=postgresql");
    if($connection) {
       echo 'connected';
    } else {
        echo 'there has been an error connecting';
    } 

     
   $result = pg_query($connection, 'SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_astext(ST_Makeline(geom))) FROM tabla_datos'); 
    $arr = pg_fetch_all($result);

?>
```

After a some time of trying things I noticed that the problem seems to be when I add this line

```
//var json_data = "<?php echo $arr ?>";
```

The rest of the php code is not a problem, but that line (even commented) breaks everything.
Does anyone know what could be happening?